# Generate a Auto Incremental ticket number with

Tags: php

I have been using the following code for few days now. and it works perfectly. but the app was used by a single user before. but now i need the app to be used by 10 people at once. the problem is that it shows the same number if the users are logged in the same time..and inserts the same ticket number from all 10 users.

can anyone suggest me how can i show a different number to every logged in user/

```
$query_cust_ts_number = "SELECT * FROM cust_comp ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$db->Execute($query_cust_ts_number);

while($row = $db->FetchArray()){
    $cust_ts_number = $row['cust_ts_number'];
}
$entsplit = explode('-', $cust_ts_number);
$entrynum = $entsplit[1];   
$newentryno = $entrynum + 1; 
$entrynoxx = sprintf('%04d', $newentryno);
$cust_ts_number = "TS-$entrynoxx";
```

Comment: What is this? MySQL? Use AUTO_INCREMENT on your ID. PostgreSQL, use a sequence. Something else?

Comment: Its MySQL and i am using AUTO_INCREMENT on ID. that not the issue ...the issue is ..say first user logged in and got ticket number (TS-0001) while he was typing the info the second user also logged in ..and he also got the number (TS-0001) ..since my code is looking for the last number ..so when they submit the form both will be submitting (TS-0001) i want to avoid that.

Comment: If you're using AUTO_INCREMENT, that won't happen. You won't get the same number twice. Just generate the TS number for the ID. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reserve an unique identifier, persist it to the database and before doing that check whether the unique identifier already exists (your database can probably do this for you). But it's easier to just use your database engine's increment id and derive a ticket number from that.